# Is it possible to deploy smart contract source code using remix?

Tags: contract-deployment, remix

I use [remix ide](https://remix.ethereum.org).

I want the source code of my contact to be published and visible in Etherscan.
I do next things:

1. Write some sample Smart Contract
2. Open "Compile" tab, check that there are no errors
3. Open "Run" tab -> Press Create Button, confirm metamask transaction
4. Wait for contract to be deployed copy address of just created contract
5. Open this contract in Etherscan

At the last step, I faced the problem I can see only "Transaction" and "Contract Code" tabs. Like [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc088bfafc62904f3f88507f0156bf5929c292e30#code).

But I want to see "Contract Source" Tab, like [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xa3af1cac819ff4c7385a869193b5507d91cfd189#code).

Is that possible with the remix? how to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, seems It's kind of duplicate, what I'm asking is step 13 in that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to go through the verifier at etherscan. You'll have to copy&paste the source code from remix and exactly specify the compiler version you have used for the deployment. If the bytecodes match 1:1 the source code will be accepted and attached to the smart contract at etherscan.

Comment: Just to clarify in etherscan I need to go MISC -> Verify Contract