# Where does etherscan gets contracts code?

Tags: solidity, etherscan

On etherscan.io there is a contract`s source code tab, where does Etherscan get this code? If developers make it available for Etherscan then is it necessary for them to public it or specifically make it available on Etherscan? 
[image]

For example this code of cryptokittes can be found on Etherscan along with several other dapps.

Answer (score 2):

Developers have to manually upload the code to etherscan.io and prove that it corresponds to the bytecode of the contract instance.

More details here:
[Is it possible to deploy smart contract source code using remix?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39300/is-it-possible-to-deploy-smart-contract-source-code-using-remix/39306#39306)

Comment: For a walkthrough of how to do it / how it works, see https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/16/verifying-contract-source-code/.