# Understand inter-operation between typical DApp and its underlying smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, dapp-development, dapps

I am a newbie to `Ethereum` and start to study some typical implementations of commonly-used `DApp`.

So basically for the popular `dapp` on this list (https://www.stateofthedapps.com/rankings/platform/ethereum), it can provide pointers to the underlying smart contracts of each `dapp`. However, after reading the code of several apps, I have the following questions:

1. Why some smart contracts seems **super trivial**, comparing to the functionality of the `dapp`? For instance this one, [life book](https://www.stateofthedapps.com/dapps/life-book), its only leveaged smart contract is [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7b6e3182ef627de759ceca4a8360166b050e5dc1?utm_source=StateOfTheDApps#code), which basically just provides some delegation utilities. Very trivial. Indeed by checking out this app (http://lifebook.club/?utm_source=StateOfTheDApps#/), I was expecting the corresponding smart contract to at least have some "storage" facilities, in order to store some user inputs.
2. So I understood that a `dapp` include front end and back end, for which the front end is some `js` code while the backend, who resides on the `Ethereum` are one or several smart contracts. But this still seems pretty shallow to me, for instance for the most popular app (https://www.stateofthedapps.com/dapps/idex), it also only contains one smart contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a0c0DBEcC7E4D658f48E01e3fA353F44050c208?utm_source=StateOfTheDApps#code), which seems very mundane and a bit trivial to me (comparing to the `Java` and `C++` projects I am familiar with); I am supersized that such a simple smart contract is capable of supporting the whole app for "decentralized exchange for trading Ethereum (ERC-20) tokens". Am I missed anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're looking at the [proxy contract](https://medium.com/@blockchain101/the-basics-of-upgradable-proxy-contracts-in-ethereum-479b5d3363d6) for managing contract versions, etc. The proxy contract points to the main contract but the proxy contract isn't the main contract itself.
2. Yes, it's that "trivial" to setup an exchange with Ethereum. The network was designed for these types of operations. There are some classic examples like [crowdsales](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale) on the ethereum website. The heavier lifting is often with security issues, versioning, frontend, etc.

Comment: Good question. TBH I wanted to link the "main contract" in my answer above, but I've been unable to find it. I'm not familiar with their proxy contract and I've had no luck poking at it. Even if we find the main contract, we might not recognize it because we'll only see the raw source/assembly unless somebody has [uploaded the solidity code to etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40468/where-does-etherscan-gets-contracts-code)... Anyway, this is probably a good topic for another question.  Somebody should be able to figure it out.